# In Mysql 6.3 when Exporting the Data as Dump- The Error will come as Could Not Get Mysql Dump version

Tags: mysql-workbench, mysql-5.7

Its Gives error as Workbench was unable to get mysqldump version.Please verify the log for more information.

It causes after updating the Mysql Workbench to 6.3 in Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Purge the package and make a clean install again. I encountered similar errors when trying to update the workbench instead of making a clean install.

Comment: Yes. I Completlt remove everything and tried.But still not fixed.    sudo apt-get purge -y mysql-server mysql-common

Comment: You did not purge the workbench. Try `sudo apt-get purge -y mysql*`